# Chrome remote debugging not working on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 Windows 7

Tags: android, google-chrome

I can't get Chrome remote debugging on windows 7 to work with my Samsung galaxy tab 4 tablet. I've downloaded the latest USB driver from Samsung's site (ver.1.5.45.0) and have Android 4.4.2 and latest Chrome on Windows 7. On my tablet notification panel instead of "USB debugging connected" I only see "Connected as a media device"!

I can get remote debugging working on the same Windows machine with an Android phone or on a Mac, so I'm pretty sure the problem is related to Samsung's USB driver for Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

> On my tablet notification panel instead of "USB debugging connected" I
>   only see "Connected as a media device"!

You have selected the wrong settings page.

Look through this tutotial
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

USB debugging you will find under Developer options tab, which you have to enable firstly

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have already enabled `USB debugging`

Comment: Do you have adb tool running on your PC? If not, install android SDK or download adb separately [link](http://www.chip.de/downloads/Minimal-ADB-and-Fastboot_62500183.html), run the server with command "adb start-server" and try to connect your device once again

Answer (score 0):

Click the "Connected as Media Device" in your notifications area, and then change the connection method from MTP to "Camera (PTP)"